# Display form if not a member

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

Here is my code. Debugged it through, echoing the form alone works and the php script works alone, however running into trouble when putting them both together

```
<?php
  $check = $mysqli->query("SELECT is_member FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
  $isMember = $check->fetch_assoc();
  if ($isMember == 0){
    echo '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
      <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="$username">
      <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="H4K679J6Y5T7C">
      <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
      </form>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: @Fred -ii- Can you spot any obvious mistakes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch_assoc()` doesn't return a column - it returns a row as an *associative array* of column names and values. If there's a user row at all, an array will be returned; this will not equal 0 no matter the value of `is_member`. If no matching row is found, `null` is returned, but I presume that's not the problem here.

Leaving all error checking aside for a moment, you might mean to say:

```
$row = $check->fetch_assoc();
$isMember = $row['is_member'];

if ($isMember == 0) { ... }
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I suppose I should also change it where it somehow previously worked in my other documents! Thank you Paul